# How can I get the Account information into the Partial View while still knowing if the User IsAuthenticated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, partial-views

I want to show a certain section only if the user logged in.  I have this set up as a Partial View.

```
@Html.Partial("ListPartial")
```

This part I can do by wrapping everything within that Partial View like this:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { 
    <h1>Stuff I want to show<h1>
}
```

When the user logs in, the code within the UserController looks like this:

```
return this.RedirectToAction<HomeController>(controller => controller.Index(uiUser));
```

So, what I want the "Stuff I want to show" is some User Accounts.  This User Account information is accessed in the AccountController like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Accounts(Int64 userId)
{
    var serviceAccounts = _accountManager.GetAccounts(userId);
    var accounts = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ServiceModels.Account>,List<Models.AccountModel>>(serviceAccounts);
    return View(accounts);
}
```

How can I get the Account information into the Partial View while still knowing if the User IsAuthenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call HtmlAction from within your partial if they are authenticated and pass it the parameters you need (or did I miss why you can't use this?)

Answer (score 0):

Just make your partial view strongly typed

```
@model Namespace.AccountModel
```

and pass the account model into your partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("ListPartial", Model)
```